# Test if adjacent rows are both significant from 0

Tags: r

I want to do a t-test on the adjacent rows (1-2, 3-4, 5-6) in my data frame. I want to test if the adjacent rows are significantly greater than 0. How do I do this on the whole data frame?
A t-test like this:

```
t.test(x=rowname,y=NULL,alternative="one.sided", alternative = "greater")
```

For example: Are `hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataTissue` and `hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataSerum` both larger than 0?

```
                              HEP015         mm7        s26  TxHEP-014  TxHEP-015  TxHEP-018      vs29
hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataTissue  0.8234702  1.18956279  0.6145471 -1.1804234 -2.9679366 -1.2382820 -1.856565
hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataSerum  -4.7975142 -1.79686065 -0.6652281 -3.0752460 -3.3742772 -3.8129578 -1.099334
hsa-miR-93-5p.dataTissue  -0.2943401 -0.02306152  0.3097169 -2.0754544  0.3720528  2.1457004  2.003187
hsa-miR-93-5p.dataSerum    1.2905805 -2.07963898 -1.7277941 -1.9811846 -0.7549379 -0.9258338 -2.319956
hsa-miR-92b-3p.dataTissue -0.5874168 -1.55601781  0.8656526 -0.3436976 -2.8644071  1.2470288  4.652237
hsa-miR-92b-3p.dataSerum  -1.9323028 -1.53377562 -0.9441492 -2.7669216 -2.5563865 -1.1790849  2.637090
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your example? How exactly are `hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataTissue` and `hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataSerum` both larger than 0? Perhaps illustrate that specific `t.test` as the example.

Comment: I want to test if the rowmean is larget than 0.

Comment: The combined rowmean or each row mean individually?

Comment: Correct. Average row mean

Comment: Still unclear, but assuming this is a data.framed named `df`, I think you may want to use: `apply(df, 1, t.test, alternative = "greater")`

Comment: Thanks, that works. How could I then compare the two adjacent results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is in a `data.frame` named `df`, one approach is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

row_results <- apply(df, 1, function(x) glance(t.test(x, alternative = "greater")))
row_results <- rbind_all(row_results)
row_results$name <- rownames(df)
# row_results
# Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
# 
#     estimate  statistic   p.value parameter   conf.low conf.high                      name
#        (dbl)      (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)     (dbl)                     (chr)
# 1 -0.6593753 -1.1179897 0.8468370         6 -1.8054369       Inf hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataTissue
# 2 -2.6602026 -4.6508774 0.9982498         6 -3.7716602       Inf  hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataSerum
# 3  0.3482573  0.6410169 0.2726011         6 -0.7074507       Inf  hsa-miR-93-5p.dataTissue
# 4 -1.2141093 -2.5674955 0.9787610         6 -2.1329943       Inf   hsa-miR-93-5p.dataSerum
# 5  0.2019113  0.2219719 0.4158491         6 -1.5656549       Inf hsa-miR-92b-3p.dataTissue
# 6 -1.1822187 -1.7248956 0.9323470         6 -2.5140465       Inf  hsa-miR-92b-3p.dataSerum
```

It appears, your `rowname` is actually two variables, therefore, I would break them up, like so:

```
library(tidyr)
row_results <- separate(row_results, name, c("name", "type"), sep = "\\.")
```

Which allows us to `group_by` the new `name` variable and create a new indicator variable, `both_significant`:

```
row_results %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(both_significant = all(p.value > 0.8))
```

You will likely want to change the logic to `p.value < 0.05`, but I wanted to have some `TRUE` examples in the results:

```
# Source: local data frame [6 x 9]
# Groups: name [3]
#
#     estimate  statistic   p.value parameter   conf.low conf.high           name       type both_significant
#        (dbl)      (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)     (dbl)          (chr)      (chr)            (lgl)
# 1 -0.6593753 -1.1179897 0.8468370         6 -1.8054369       Inf hsa-miR-99a-5p dataTissue             TRUE
# 2 -2.6602026 -4.6508774 0.9982498         6 -3.7716602       Inf hsa-miR-99a-5p  dataSerum             TRUE
# 3  0.3482573  0.6410169 0.2726011         6 -0.7074507       Inf  hsa-miR-93-5p dataTissue            FALSE
# 4 -1.2141093 -2.5674955 0.9787610         6 -2.1329943       Inf  hsa-miR-93-5p  dataSerum            FALSE
# 5  0.2019113  0.2219719 0.4158491         6 -1.5656549       Inf hsa-miR-92b-3p dataTissue            FALSE
# 6 -1.1822187 -1.7248956 0.9323470         6 -2.5140465       Inf hsa-miR-92b-3p  dataSerum            FALSE
```